# How can I make my bootstrap collapse toggles mutually exclusive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

If I've got two buttons toggling collapsible cards, I'd like to make `button2` collapse `target1` before expanding `target2`, and vice-versa:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="btn-group mx-auto">
  <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target1" aria-expanded="false">
    button1
  </button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target2" aria-expanded="false">
    button2
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="target1">
 <div class="card card-body">
   ...
 </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="target2">
 <div class="card card-body">
   ...
 </div>
</div>
```

Currently if `button1` and `button2` are clicked one after the other, both cards remain expanded.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following markup to achieve that.

> Note: at the time of writing Bootstrap was still in **beta 3**.

```html
<div id="group">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-group mx-auto">
            <button class="btn" type="button" data-parent="#group" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target1" aria-expanded="false">
                button 1
            </button>

            <button class="btn" type="button" data-parent="#group" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target2" aria-expanded="false">
                button 2
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
        <div class="collapse" id="target1">
            <div class="card card-body">
                CARD 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
        <div class="collapse" id="target2">
            <div class="card card-body">
                CARD 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

This example is making use of the `data-parent=".selector"` feature of bootstrap, which you have to define on the toggle buttons. Additionally wrap the collapsibles into a div with the selector given above. (I used `#group` in this case.)

Also, as there is a [bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966) with this built in feature in bootstrap, you also have to wrap the collapsibles in a `.panel`.

UPDATE:
Apparently the divs that wrap the collapsibles does not necessarily have to have the `.panel` class, but it is still important that the `.collapse` divs must not be immediate children of the `#group` element.

UPDATE 2:
The updated markup for **Bootstrap 4.1** is as follows.

```html
<div id="group">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn-group mx-auto">
            <!-- Note removed 'data-parent' attribute -->
            <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target1" aria-expanded="false">
                button 1
            </button>

            <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target2" aria-expanded="false">
                button 2
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
        <!-- Note relocated 'data-parent' attribute -->
        <div class="collapse" id="target1" data-parent="#group">
            <div class="card card-body">
                CARD 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
        <div class="collapse" id="target2" data-parent="#group">
            <div class="card card-body">
                CARD 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, @dferenc

Comment: Note - In Bootstrap v4 (non-beta), the `data-parent=".selector"` variable **has** to go in the `<div class="collapse">` target elements, **NOT** the `<button data-toggle="collapse">` element for the "accordion" feature to work. @dferenc

Comment: Just tried this code as-is with Bootstrap 4, and it still shows the behaviour OP is wanting to avoid.

Comment: @thosphor Thanks for the comment. Please note, that at the time of OP [Bootstrap 4 was still just in **beta 3** state](https://www.bootstrapdash.com/bootstrap-4-release-date/). I just have converted the sample code above to a snippet to reference the beta 3 library it meant to be used with. Also, I've included the sample markup for Bootsrap 4.1.

Comment: @dferenc Thanks for putting in the effort. I just wanted to flag to others who are still using this answer as a reference.